# Java CSVeed library, option for quote inside unquoted field?

Tags: java, csv

I'm **benching** several Java libraries to parse csv files. I can't find a solution for the **CSVeed** library with this line :

```
af,dekh"iykh'ya,Dekh"iykh'ya,13,,34.60345,69.2405
```

I have this error :

```
org.csveed.report.CsvException: Illegal state transition:
Parsing symbol QUOTE_SYMBOL [34] in state INSIDE_FIELD
19970: af,dekh
```

I understand  very well what happen unfortunately I tried different blend of **options** without succeed. Is there a way?
In fact the **perfect** line of 7 cols should be :

```
af,dekh\"iykh\'ya,Dekh\"iykh\'ya,13,,34.60345,69.2405
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
af,dekh"iykh'ya,Dekh"iykh'ya,13,,34.60345,69.2405
```

To parse this in the following fields you'll have to turn quoting off in your parser:

```
af
dekh"iykh'ya
Dekh"iykh'ya
13
<null>
34.60345
69.2405
```

If quoting can not be turned off, you could use `setQuote(char symbol)` and provide an unused char as parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately quoting can't be turned off (by default it's "), there no option ignore quote alone (or something like this) and if I provide an unused char like '§' (or even \t), it works but it increases incredibly the time of computation and I really don't know why.... I sent a mail to the author of the library and create an issue on his Github.

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1 Yes, I looked it up while writing the answer - looks like only `setQuote()` can be used. Strange that this would become slower. However, `§` is a 'high ascii' value, so if your data is utf-8 that would use more than one byte - althoug `\t` is a single byte. Maybe test with a null byte? ( 0x00 or \0 ). Maybe I'll have a look at the source code.

Comment: In fact `setQuote('0x00')` is not allowed and `setQuote('\0')` produces en error with EOL of the problematic line.

Comment: Erratum : `setQuote('\t')` produces also en error with EOL of the problematic line.

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1 Did you try `setQuote(0x00)` or `setQuote(0)` - without the `'`? I had a quick look at the source code - setQuote() replaces the default `"` char, so I don't see a reason why it should be slower (I didn't look very deep though). Are you sure it's a lot slower? Are the same amount of rows read in both tests?

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1 Strange - what if you use '*' as a quick test?

Comment: Ok I do currently some quick tests on Windows (with\r\n as EOL), I'm going right away on Linux to test efficiently!

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1 For Windows, that would be `\r\n` not `\n\r`; or just `\n` depending on you file.

Comment: Ok I agree, rapid tests show that it's the same time for `setQuote('\t')` and `setQuote('§')` for the same csv file. I have '*' in my file. I think I have a problem of memory with this library in my bench : this library needs perhaps more memory than the others I test and it's the reason why it looks for me slower.

Comment: @Yannick.fr.rennes1 Ah ok, but that's a different problem then. Did this solve your original problem with the quotes?

Comment: I'm going to mark this post as solved because I think there's no option to solve directly the problem. And thank you for the help!